# WiX Toolset - CustomAction for uninstall running after RemoveFiles

Tags: wix, sequence, custom-action

On install I add a configuration key to a DB using a command line tool.  On uninstall, I'm now trying to remove that configuration key.  On an upgrade, I need to remove then add the configuration key back.

Here's my CustomAction "redacted" code:

```
<CustomAction Id="Unset_AppName_Version_Cmd"
              Property="Unset_AppName_Version"
              Execute="immediate"
              Value="&quot;[SystemFolder]cmd.exe&quot; /C &quot;&quot;[SOMEDIR]SomeClTool&quot; &quot;uninstall:appname&quot;&quot;" />

<CustomAction Id="Unset_AppName_Version"
              BinaryKey="WixCA"
              DllEntry="CAQuietExec"
              Execute="immediate"
              Return="check"
              Impersonate="yes" />
```

Note: I've tried several values for execute, including oncePerProcess, firstSequence, and immediate.

Here's my InstallExecuteSequence "redacted" code:

```
<Custom Action="Unset_AppName_Version_Cmd" Sequence="1215">
    (!AppName = 3 AND (&amp;AppName = 3 OR &amp;AppName = 2))     
</Custom>
<Custom Action="Unset_AppName_Version" Sequence="1216">
    (!AppName = 3 AND (&amp;AppName = 3 OR &amp;AppName = 2))
</Custom>
```

Note: Again, I tried to move around the sequence used.  In the above example before InstallValidate, but also before RemoveFiles, RemoveODBC, etc.

Nothing has worked for me.  In all instances, the

```
Executing op: ActionStart(Name=Unset_AppName_Version,,)
```

line is being run after RemoveFiles, so my custom action fails with:

```
CAQuietExec:  The system cannot find the path specified.
CAQuietExec:  Error 0x80070001: Command line returned an error.
CAQuietExec:  Error 0x80070001: CAQuietExec Failed
```

After this, my installation gets rolled back.

Also, is this condition correct for run on uninstall or reinstall?

```
(!AppName = 3 AND (&amp;AppName = 3 OR &amp;AppName = 2))
```

Thanks

Update 7/31/2015

While I still do not have a working solution, I have made enough changes that it makes sense to post my current code.

Here's my updated CustomAction "redacted" code:

```
<CustomAction Id="Unset_AppName_Version_Cmd" 
              Property="QtExecCmdLine"
              Value="&quot;[SystemFolder]cmd.exe&quot; /C &quot;&quot;[SOMEDIR]SomeClTool&quot; &quot;uninstall:appname&quot;&quot;"
              Execute="immediate" />

<CustomAction Id="Unset_AppName_Version"
              BinaryKey="WixCA"
              DllEntry="CAQuietExec"
              Execute="immediate"
              Return="ignore" />
```

Note: These changes were made based on Kiran's much appreciated suggestions and to mimic some taskkill commands that are working for me.

Example of working code:

```
<CustomAction Id="TaskKill_erl_exe_Cmd"
              Property="QtExecCmdLine"
              Value='"[SystemFolder]taskkill.exe" /F /IM erl.exe /T'                  
              Execute="immediate" />

<CustomAction Id="TaskKill_erl_exe"
              BinaryKey="WixCA"
              DllEntry="CAQuietExec"
              Execute="immediate"
              Return="ignore"/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things here.

-You are trying to execute the custom action in **immediate** mode using the Wix provided  inbuilt Quiet Execution Custom Action.

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/qtexec.html

If you want to make use of **CAQuietExec** in **immediate** mode, the documentation clearly suggests that you have to set the  **WixQuietExecCmdLine** property.

I dont see that being done in your case.

In your case, i see that you are setting a property named **Unset_AppName_Version** in the immediate mode. This just wont work.

-If you are trying to use **CAQuietExec** in **deferred** mode, your authoring of the custom actions in the pasted code snippet  will work, as  that would lead to populating the value of the inbuilt special property "CustomActionData"

-If the command line tool that you are trying to launch is installed by the msi package, then the custom action with Id="Unset_AppName_Version" has to be sequenced after "InstallFiles" standard action for the case of  Install/Upgrade/Re-install.

For the case of uninstall, i am assuming you will have a seperate custom action which invokes this command line tool with a different set of parameters and it should be sequenced before "RemoveFiles" standard action.

-Finally, yes your condition is correct and will invoke the action on re-install or uninstall of the feature.

-Also when you run your msi package, if you want to confirm if the command line tool was indeed launched, you can have a utility named "ProcessMonitor" running. ProcessMonitor is from the Sysinternals suite. Keep the tool running by setting the appropriate filters.
If your  tool is ever launched, ProcessMonitor will indicate the same to you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks.  I had already switched to Property="QtExecCmdLine", which seems to work.  Is WixQuietExecCmdLine a better choice?  I tried sequencing before RemoveFiles (I'm only looking to run this on uninstall or on the uninstall portion of a MajorUpgrade).  I even placed the custom actions in the 1200+ sequence range with no condition.  It runs in the selected sequence, but tries again after RemoveFiles, which causes a failure and a rollback.  I've tried oncePerProcess and firstSequence to try to get it to only run once, but nothing seems to keep WiX from trying to run after RemoveFiles.

Comment: Inspect your built msi using Orca. Orca is part of the windows installer SDK. Inspect the InstallExecuteSequence table and check the sequence numbers assigned to your custom action as well as RemoveFiles. If its executing after RemoveFiles, then it is sequenced later. Sequence numbers are really relative and they can change depending on the number of custom actions present. Good way is to inspect the msi package using Orca.  Also, have you inspected using Process Monitor to see if the correct command has been invoked?

Comment: Thanks again Kiran.  I checked Orca and things looked fine, sequences 1211...1214.  In the verbose log, I see "Action ended 12:25:58: MigrateFeatureStates".  Then I see my conditions testing as false, so the CustomActions get skipped.  The command side (Unset_AppName_Version_Cmd) gets runs after "WriteEnvironmentStrings", which seems okay (before RemoveFiles).  The problem is that Unset_AppName_Version doesn't get run until the InstallFinalize phase.  I don't understand the delay.  What do you recommend as the settings for Execute and Impersonate (I got rid of this) for Unset_AppName_Version?

Comment: If Unset_AppName_Version doesn't get run until InstallFinalize, its very likely a deferred action. Would you be able to upload your entire log file somewhere?  Also, did you verify that the correct command was being executed using Process Monitor?  How about you make  Execute=Deferred and Impersonate=No?  To get a better understanding of how custom actions execute, read:  www.installsite.org/pages/en/isnews/200108/

Comment: Hi Kiran, I've made edits to my original question to show you my current CustomActions.  I have been reviewing that link you mentioned since having this issue, but I'll review it again. Also, you can view the entire log at https://www.dropbox.com/s/sour7cl79ovo5d7/msi.log?dl=0  Thanks

Comment: I inspected your log file and in the log file i do not see entries for either Unset_AppName_Version_Cmd nor Unset_AppName_Version. Also , can you please post the snippet of your InstallExecuteSequence table. On another note, your Unset_AppName_Version_Cmd  custom action should be scheduled right before the custom action which launches the command. In your case , schedule Unset_AppName_Version_Cmd  right before Unset_AppName_Version

Comment: Please search for "Unset_".  You'll find the real application names.  The "AppName" portion of the string in my examples was used not to show the real name.  Yes, I scheduled the custom action with Cmd just before the second custom action.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working for me:

```
<CustomAction Id="Unset_AppName_Version_Cmd" 
              Property="QtExecCmdLine"
              Value="&quot;[SystemFolder]cmd.exe&quot; /C &quot;&quot;[SOMEDIR]SomeClTool&quot; &quot;uninstall:appname&quot;&quot;"
              Execute="immediate" />

<CustomAction Id="Unset_AppName_Version"
              BinaryKey="WixCA"
              DllEntry="CAQuietExec"
              Execute="immediate"
              Return="ignore" />
```

And in the InstallExecuteSequence:

```
<Custom Action="Unset_AppName_Version_Cmd" Sequence="1215">
    (!AppName = 3 AND (&amp;AppName = 3 OR &amp;AppName = 2))     
</Custom>
<Custom Action="Unset_AppName_Version" Sequence="1216">
    (!AppName = 3 AND (&amp;AppName = 3 OR &amp;AppName = 2))
</Custom>
```

The issue seems to be that something got messed up in my VM with all the rollbacks.

The main problem that I had was that I initially tried to name the property in the "Unset_AppName_Version_Cmd" CustomAction.

Thanks again to Kiran for all his help.

Comment: I am glad that you have got it to work. What was the exact change now compared to your earlier version?

Comment: It wasn't so much a change as there seemed to be an issue with a VM I was using.  A CustomAction I had deleted was still showing up in the logs, so I reverted back to an earlier snapshot.